# Normal distribtuion calculation in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I try to calculate normal pdf but because I get 0 from covariance matrix determinant all my calculation messed up. How could I deal with that problem> Is there any other approximation method for normal distribution?

Comment: So you want a PDF for uncorrelated data? The probability would be zero... no?

Comment: Anyway, this is a statistics question

Comment: What exactly is you problem? What computation is messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you did not give any reasonable information what exactly your problem is, I will try to answer your questions in two ways.

---

#### You have some datapoints and would like to estimate their distribution parameters

Assuming your data is in the vector `Y`, you just can do

```
mu = mean(Y);
sigma = std(Y);
```

If we are talking about multivariate normal distributions, you have to replace `std` by `cov` and get the covariance matrix. If you have `std(Y) == 0` you always recorded the same value. In this case estimating a distribution is trivial - just take a distribution with the probability of your recorded value being one. In the multivariate case, you should not have zeros on the diagonal of your matrix - otherwise, you again just have the same value in this variable.

---

#### You have some distribution parameters and would like to compute the corresponding distribution function:

In this case, you just can call the builtin MATLAB function `normpdf` like

```
normpdf(X,mu,sigma)
```

where `X` is a vector of points you want to evaluate the function at and `mu`, `sigma` are your distribution parameters for the mean and the standard deviation. Note, however, that `sigma` has to be greater zero (otherwise the distribution would be very degenerated)

For the multivariate case, you may use

```
mvnpdf(X,MU,SIGMA)
```

with sigma being the covariance matrix.

All those functions can be found in the MATLAB documentation.

If my answer did not help you, you should certainly rework your question.